# ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged does not fire when programatically changing the index

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, selectedindexchanged

I am working with Windows Forms in C#.net.
I have 2 `ComboBox` and 3 `TextBox` on a form.  When I change the value in `ComboBox1` (by interating with the item in the UI) it changes the items and selected item in `ComboBox2`.

When the selected index of `ComboBox2` is changed, it *should*  change the text in all of the `TextBox`, but it seems that the `SelectedIndexChanged` is not being fired.

```
public void comboSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //when the selection changes...
        // 1) cast the sender as a comboBox
        ComboBox cBox = (ComboBox)sender;

        // 2) identify the sender
        if (cBox.Name.ToString() == "ComboBox1")
        {   //this is the 1st combo box                

            //load the children of the new selection into the form
            //child of ComboBox1 is ComboBox2
            ComboBox2.Items.Clear();
            ComboBox2.Text = null;
            string selected = null;

            foreach (string item in {"box2_item1","box2_item2"})
            {
                ComboBox2.Items.Add(item);
            }
            //need to set the selection last, because this will (hopefully) fire the selection changed event on the child

            if (selected != null)
            {//here I am actually getting the selected item from XML
                ComboBox2.SelectedItem = selected;
            }
            else
            {//this should be action that is initiated, which should definitely change the selected index
                ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
        }
        else if (cBox.Name.ToString() == "ComboBox2")
        {   //this is the 2nd combobox              

            //load the children of the new selection into the form
            //the textBoxes are the children
            TextBox1.Text = "some new text that I am getting from XML";
            TextBox2.Text = "some other new text as above.";
            TextBox3.Text = "same thing, one more time" ;
        }
        else
        {   //I messed something up, because the combobox name is invalid
            Debug.Write("Unreachable code encountered: The combobox name {" + cBox.Name.ToString() + "} is not valid!");
            return;
        }
```

I've tried to simplify this, and hopefully I haven't overdone it with the simplification.  As noted, I am getting data from an XML file, and *ideally* the goal is to use this form to read from and write to the XML file.  All of the XML seems to me working fine, so I have left all of that out.

both of the boxes' `SelectedIndexChanged` events are tied to the code above. What happens is when I change the value of `ComboBox1` the values of `ComboBox2` are changed, and the selected item is cleared, but the `ComboBox2.SeletedIndexChanged` event is never fired (breakpoins show me that the code clock is never re-entered), so the none of the `TextBox` are updated with new data.

I hope that all makes sense and somone can help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I don't see a reason for these ComboBoxes to share the same event handler.  They don't seem to share any common code.  Not sure what your `selected` variable is doing in this code.  It looks rather pointless.

Comment: @Crowcoder + Med.Amine.Touil  Thanks to you both!  I don't know why that didn't occur to me! I don't know why the event isn't fired on its own, but this is certainly a functional workaround!

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks for your input.  There is alot more that is going to happen here, and both combo boxes will end up doing the same thing, to thier respective children, hence the desire to avoid redundant code, and have both use the same event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event handler is just a method so you can just call it. If your handler is named `ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged` you can do:

```
        ...
        else
        {//this should be action that is initiated, which should definitely change the selected index
            ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;
            ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(ComboBox2, new EventArgs());
        }
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Fire the SelectedIndexChanged event by your self in `comboSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` method by calling

```
ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(ComboBox2, new EventArgs());
```